# Is there annotation in java or micronaut that validates if given string can be deserialized to float or double?

Tags: java, hibernate, micronaut

I need to call a PUT or POST request with a payload

```
{
name:"dummy",
marks:"90.50"
}
```

And I have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name="Student")
public class Student {
       private String name;

       @Min(value = 0, message = "Marks should be positive.")
       @Digits(integer = 2, fraction = 2, message = "value must be positive and 2 digits whole number")
       private Float marks;
 }
```

If I call API with marks as negative it gives me an appropriate error saying "Marks should be positive." because of the @Max annotation.
Similar to it, how can I show an appropriate message if I call API with invalid marks like "90.abc" or "abcd".

PS: I already have validation on the frontend, but need validation in the backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

I´d say your `marks` property is already a `Float`. So how should it be possible to pass a `String` to this property? Isn´t it possible to directly design the API to have a number type for the JSON value type of `marks`?

If you really need the validation if a String is a number, it can be done with a `@Pattern`, e.g. `@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\$")`.